# Dynamic height of row in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, calendar

I'm creating an application which is similar with Calendar. However, I have an issue when display the calendar. I want the height of the gridview fixed with the height of the layout. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean cell height  of gridview or height gridview?

Comment: @MajidDaeiNejad height of cell. For example, the layout for gridview is 100, and I have 5 rows. Then, the height of the cell is 20. Hope you understand what I meant

Comment: maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482989/how-to-assign-wrap-content-as-height-to-dynamically-loaded-gridview/46350213#46350213