# How to assign wrap_content as height to dynamically loaded gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am loading gridview dynamically with buttons. So for that I am using scrollview, But if i assign wrap_content as height to gridview all the buttons are not displayed. I dont want to assign any static height for the gridview.
This is the code which I am using:

```
<ScrollView
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                  android:paddingRight="5dip" >

                  <GridView
                      android:id="@+id/gridviewtable"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height=wrap_content"
                      android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                      android:numColumns="4"
                      android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
                  </GridView>

              </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to create a new class for example

```
public class WrappingGridView extends GridView {

public WrappingGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public WrappingGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public WrappingGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightSpec = heightMeasureSpec;
    if (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
        // The great Android "hackatlon", the love, the magic.
        // The two leftmost bits in the height measure spec have
        // a special meaning, hence we can't use them to describe height.
        heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
}

}
```

also you need to change in your XML

```
<com.your.project.WrappingGridView
                android:id="@+id/gridviewtable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>
```

and finally in your java class you need to chance the object GridView to WrappingGridView

Comment: Items in grid has to have set fixed height otherwise it doesn't work well

Comment: You can use View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2;

Comment: Thanks! Classic Googlers and their half-baked APIs and Components - not fixed even after 5 years. Their GridView is exactly as buggy as their ViewPager, it does not work with wrap_content because they are so lame, they can not even resize their own components when they are filled with data programmatically through adapters...Omfg

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
int totalHeight = (count / <number of items in a row>);

    if (count % <number of items in a row> != 0) {
        totalHeight++;
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridview.getLayoutParams();

    params.height = <height of a row> * totalHeight;

    gridview.setLayoutParams(params);
    gridview.requestLayout();
```

Comment: A variant of this answer is the only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` cannot be used for subclasses of `AdapterView` (e.g. ListView and GridView). The GridView would have to get each row's height in order to calculate its own height.

Remove the `ScrollView` and the `LinearLayout`, you don't need them. The GridView already has its own scrolling logic built-in.

Comment: how to assign layout_params dynamically for gridview??

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: to assign height dynamically to gridview

Comment: That should not be necessary.

Comment: As I am loading the contents dynamically so need to assign the height dynamically.

Comment: The GridView's height will grow automatically, why do you have to change anything?

Comment: Also If I dont include scroll and linearlayout all the buttons are not visible and their positions keep on changing while scrolling

Comment: You should post your _full_ layout.

Comment: I have posted my full layout.

Comment: Then where are the buttons?

Comment: It is different layout. why do u need them.. I just want to know how to set layoutparams for gridview

Comment: Not useful answer

Answer (score -1):

This or something similar should do it. (code as i remember it)
`myImageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Answer (score -1):

This is a Frankenstein of many answers before me but it is the only thing has worked for me so far:

```
private static void resizeGridView(GridView gridView, int rows) {
    int measuredHeight = gridView.getMeasuredHeight();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = measuredHeight * rows;
    gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
    gridView.requestLayout();
}
```

Call this after you've updated the content to be displayed to the gridView.